# Apigee 401 Unauthorized with token_expired

Tags: apigee

I'm trying to create a user account through the apigee JS API. This worked just fine when I was last doing this before the holidays in mid December. Now, however, I get a 401 Unauthorized error reading `token_expired`.

Is there a way to refresh the token? I don't know why it would have expired.

This is what I'm trying. First I instantiate the data client. No problems here:

```
var dataClient;
var client_creds = {
    orgName: '*******',
    appName: '*******'
}
dataClient = new Apigee.Client(client_creds);
```

Later, when trying to create a new user, I get the `token_expired` error:

```
dataClient.request(options, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(response);
            alert("Something went wrong when trying to create the user. " + response.error)
            // Error
        } else {
            // Success - the user has been created, now login.
            dataClient.login(user.email, user.password,
                function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        //error - could not log user in
                        console.log("There was an error logging in " + user.name);
                    } else {
                        //success - user has been logged in
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

I've also tried `dataClient.signup`, but same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no refresh tokens within App Services; you'll need to follow the [login flow](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/authenticating-users-and-application-clients) in order to retrieve a new token. Note that you can specify the `ttl` parameter, like so, so you don't need to do this as frequently:

```
https://api.usergrid.com/{org}/{app}/token?ttl=604800
```

By default, this is set to 7 days, but you can change the *default* app max ttl to `0` (non-expiring) or something else like `31104000000` (365 days).

To do that, you make a `PUT` request:

```
https://api.usergrid.com/{org}/{app}/?client_id={app_client_id}&client_secret={app_client_secret}
```

With JSON payload:

```
{
    "accesstokenttl":0
}
```

Or for 1 year:

```
{
    "accesstokenttl":31104000000
}
```

Comment: Thanks- what would the downsides be with never expiring the token? In my case the token is just to gain the most default access to the application data, like create a new user and login.

Comment: Downside is that if the token is compromised, you'd have to manually invalidate it (I believe by changing the account password or making a new call to `.../token`) otherwise whoever has it could make calls using that token forever. Depends on how sensitive your data is.

Comment: I'm still a little confused with what you mean with `the login flow`. I can't log my user in since the application token created is expired and is stored in localstorage. Do I have to delete the old token? I prefer not using the client_secret, since I don't want it in the project if I can avoid it.

Comment: You can make a raw POST call tl the token endpoint and it will act like it's re logging you in. Alternatively, yes deleting the existing token out if local storage would cause the app to fail authentication, though it doesn't actually invalidate the token.

Answer (score 1):

If that doesn't work for you, the authorization tokens for the JavaScript SDK are kept in your browser's local storage.  In Chrome, use the Developer Tools.  In the Resources tab on the left hand side expand the Local Storage entry.  You should see something like "http://usergrid.dev" or something similar.  Choose that and on the right hand side you should see an entry for accessToken.  Delete that and it should solve your problem.

Comment: So how does one refresh a token? I have the same issue. Token expired and now my QA guy can't login. Is it possible to request a new token on every login? Isn't that how it's supposed to work?